# Fabric task dependencies

Tags: fabric

I am working on a fabric file to make our code deployment process a little bit easier. Now I would like to have dependencies between certain tasks, similar to what is discussed in one [here](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/452).

Let's simplify the problem and say I have two task: `build` and `deploy`. The `build` task should build our code and the `deploy` task will transfer it to a deployment server.

Now, `deploy` obviously depends on `build`, but `build` could also be a standalone task. So someone could just build the code with `fab build` or deploy the code with `fab build deploy`. But I also want people to use `fab deploy` for convenience, but then it should run `build` first. But `build` should only be executed once.

So if I include `build` into the `deploy` task and then do `fab build deploy` it will run `build` twice and then `deploy`.

Comment: If my current understanding is correct the only way to simulate this "requires" functionality at the moment with fabric is to subclass from a base task class. But for your use case subclassing looks like overkill. If the build process is expensive I would include a check if a build is necessary.

Comment: Subclassing sounds like a reasonable approach but I managed to do it a little bit simpler. Thanks for your comment tho

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to do this with the [`runs_once`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/decorators.html#fabric.decorators.runs_once) decorator and [`execute`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute) function.

The `build` task is now decorated with `runs_once` and every task that depends on `build`, e.g. `deploy`, will do `execute(build)` at the beginning. This will execute the build task or silently fail if it was already executed (thanks to the decorator).

This is more like a workaround than a solution but it works in my case. Regardless, thanks to everyone for their input

Comment: Thanks for the nice workaround - it reminds me of caching in dynamic programming. You could (like I am about to do) create a depends decorator that calls the functions that are passed into before calling the underlying function. This makes the code more "descriptive" in some sense. I'm also changing task to include run_once.